# How to set specific conditions in models.py while entering data in admin panel?

Tags: django, django-models

```
    room_category = models.ForeignKey(Cat, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    people = models.IntegerField()
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'room/', null=True, blank=True)
    actual_price = models.IntegerField()
    offer_price = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%d : %s with People : %d' % (self.number, self.room_category, self.people)
```

I want to set a condition in `offer_price` table that `offer_price < actual_price`. It should show an error while entering data in the admin panel itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add validation in the [**`.clean(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean), and add a database constraint with [*Django's constraint framework*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db.models import F, Q

class YourModel(models.Model):
    # …
    actual_price = models.IntegerField()
    offer_price = models.IntegerField()

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.actual_price <= self.offer_price:
            raise ValidationError('offer price should be lower than the actual price')
        return super().clean(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraints(
                check=Q(offer_price__lt=F('actual_price')),
                name='lower_than_actual_price'
            )
        ]
```